# set the value of input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script>
function doMath() {
    var labor = parseInt(document.getElementById('prod_price').value);
    var tax = labor * .10;

    document.getElementById('prod_description').value = tax;
}
</script>
<div>Price: <input type="text" id="prod_price" onBlur="doMath();" /></div>
<div>Tax: <input type="text" id="prod_description" readonly="true" /></div>
```

how to make this one..if price is lower than 100 , then tax must be display as 5
and if price highest than 100, then tax must be 20

Comment: Don't put jQuery in the title, add a tag for it (but it seems you aren't using it anyway).

Comment: What if the price is neither higher nor lower than 100, i.e. exactly 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
function doMath() {
    var labor = parseInt(document.getElementById('prod_price').value);
    if(labor<100)
    {
        document.getElementById('prod_description').value = "5";
    }
    else if(labor>100)
    {
        document.getElementById('prod_description').value = "20";
    }
}
```